# There was an error while executing `VBoxManage` homestead up

Tags: laravel, homestead

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

```
Command: ["startvm", "b34e3109-0211-457e-9e17-e39a31b98a97", "--type", "headless"]
```

Stderr:

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: The configuration constructor in main failed due to a COM error. Check the release log of the VM for further details. (VERR_MAIN_CONFIG_CONSTRUCTOR_COM_ERROR)
    VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Comment: What version of vagrant and virtual box are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Windows 10? If so then follow these three things...

1. Check and enable Virtualization at Motherboard BIOS.
2. Check if you have enable Hyper V in Windows 10 Optional features.
3. Check if you have enable WSL on Windows 10